# Why does OS X automatically logout my user?

Tags: macos, filevault, logout

I have a new MacBook Air set up with FileVault.

In the Security Preference pane I have "Require password 1 hour after sleep or screen saver begins" enabled, but the "Logout after 60 minutes of inactivity" is disabled.

When I leave the computer on overnight I manually lock the screen (from the Keychain status menu bar, which I enabled via the Keychain Access preferences).

Alas, in the morning I find that instead of a locked screen I see the login window, after my user was logged out with all applications terminated... (e.g. Firefox thinks it previously crashed when I launch it).

This type of behavior only started after I enabled FileVault.

Why is this happening?
How do I prevent such auto-logout?

Comment: Something interesting in `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`? Any error messages through the night? Did this problem appear repeatedly, or only once, maybe twice?

Comment: @Daniel - since I need to leave some processes running continuously

Comment: @Daniel - nothing interesting in console log.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but it was because "Logout after 60 minutes of inactivity" checkbox was enabled.

Comment: Seems I fooled with some of the prefs after I upgraded to Yosemite.  Now it seems I'm logged off when idle as well, where is the "Logout after 60 minutes of inactivity" checkbox, I haven't seen it.

Comment: I found the "Logoff after 60 minutes of inactivity" setting, see this entry: http://superuser.com/questions/867370/mac-os-x-yosemite-how-to-disable-automatic-logout-when-idle

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced a similar issue. My MacBook Pro was actually *rebooting itself* during the night, so in the morning, I found it displaying the login screen instead of where I left it in the afternoon (converting a TV recording from my DVR).

You can check when your MacBook was rebooted the last time. To do so, open `Terminal.app` and enter

```
uptime
```

The command will output something like this:

```
 9:44  up 1 day, 14:19, 1 user, load averages: 0.38 0.29 0.32
```

This displays the current time (9:44) and how long ago the machine was rebooted the last time (1 day, 14 hours, and 19 minutes ago).

This won't exactly solve your problem but help you to find or eliminate a particular root cause (the reboot).