# Mac OS X Yosemite - How to Disable Automatic Logout when idle?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-yosemite, logout

It appears that since I upgraded to OS X Yosemite, and fiddled with some of the energy saver and screen saver settings, that my user is logged out due to inactivity.

Where is the setting where I can turn this off and not allow my user to be automatically logged off when inactive?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The option is found in the `System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General > Advanced` dialog.

The first option is a check box with text `Log out after [NN - spin button] minutes of inactivity`

The spin button enables one to set the number of minutes of inactivity.

Kudos to the user [Alistair McMillan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/4007/alistair-mcmillan) who posted the answer over in the [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange.

Read the full thread [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/140076/os-x-10-9-4-closes-application-when-sleeping/140077#140077).

Comment: You can not imagine how long I have tried to find this!! Thanks a lot!! (Each time I woke up in the morning, I got the 'could not logout' message, due to iTerm etc. still being open. Very annoying hehe)

Comment: This was a lifesaver! The logout was driving me craaaaa-zzzaayyy.

Answer (score 5):

You can prevent your Mac to automatically log out the current user after a set period of inactivity by this way -

1. Choose Apple menu > System Preferences
2. Click Security & Privacy
3. Click General
4. Click the lock icon to unlock it
5. Enter an administrator name and password
6. Click Advanced
7. Uncheck “Log out after... minutes of inactivity”
8. Click Ok

You can also check [OS X Yosemite: Set your Mac to log out when not in use](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18670?locale=en_US)

Comment: Nice use of step-by-step written instructions, may I suggest you add step 9 to click the <unlock-icon> to lock the user preferences?

Comment: Excellent reference to the apple support documentation also, well done.

Answer (score 1):

Go into System Preferences> Users & Groups> Then click on the button that says Automatic Logout.

Comment: There is no "Users", only "Users & Groups". No "Other Options"!

Comment: A button "Automatic Logout" does not exist there.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is for your mac screen to stay on. The great answers above will only get you part of the way there. Under the security and privacy general tab 
de-select the require password. This will stop the request for a password and allow the computer to screen to stay on if all other "screen saving" is turned off.

Caution - This will forcibly remove apple pay.

Comment: I think the answer could be more useful if you also state in your "Caution" that the computer will not be locked at all during the time the display remains on.

Answer (score 0):

i had mistaken `require password` for `log out after X minutes of inactivity`

that setting is also under the `General` tab of `Security & Privacy` near the top, first checkmark

(macOS catalina)

Comment: I see you are a new user. You can improve your answer and possibly earn up-votes by changing from your answer from describing your experience to a "how-to" achieve the goal described in the question when using macOS Catalina. For example:.  "In macOS Catalina, Follow these steps: ..."  I think that would be useful information to those who read this post going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Apple menu > System Settings..., then click Privacy & Security in the sidebar. Click ‍‍`Advanced` at the bottom. Then switch off `Log out automatically after inactivity`.